# Не могу настроить поддомены

Tags: nginx, flask, поддомены

Конфигурация следующая: сайт Flask  + NGINX на VPS  сервере Ubuntu 20.04,  домен exemple.com поддомен bla

Сайт:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__, subdomain_matching=True)
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = "example.com"

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "example.com"

@app.route("/", subdomain="bla")
def bla_index():
    return "bla.example.com"
```

NGINX  /etc/nginx/sites-available/name

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com bla.example.com;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/user/name/name.sock;
    }
}
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
```

example.com - здесь все нормально, а вот при использовании поддомена bla.example.com получаю ошибку  Internal Server Error :(

Подскажите что нужно сделать?

Comment: Если Internal Server Error, значит в логах должна быть написана какая-то подробная ошибка

Comment: c конфигом nginx у вас все нормально. Проверьте приложение

Comment: c конфигом nginx у вас все нормально. Проверьте приложение – 
Aleksey Vaganov
Вы думаете? Я грешил на то, что необходимо добавить обратное проксирование  unix:/home/user/name/name.sock;     для поддомена

Comment: /usr/share/nginx/logs/error.log  здесь нет ничего относительно этой ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Ну вобщем, где была ошибка я так и не понял.
Рабочая конфигурация блока оказалась такая:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name aihealth.site en.aihealth.site www.aihealth.site;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/kiwi/vgp/vgp.sock;
        }
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
```

Код файла:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

app = Flask(__name__, subdomain_matching=True)
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = "example.com"

bla = Blueprint("bla", __name__, subdomain="bla")


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "example.com"


bla.route("/")
def index():
    return "bla.example.com"

app.register_blueprint(bla)
```